# "Imported Content is empty" when web scraping

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets

I've been playing around with this for a couple of hours and after trying dozens of different things. I'm reaching out to see if someone can solve the riddle of scraping from this site.

Here's the webpage: https://cmro.travis-starnes.com/detail.php?idvalue=4945

and a screenshot with the data:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/PayjL.jpg

I'd like to scrape circled in red (it's at the bottom of the pic).

What formula can I use to scrape that five-digit numbers into the cell without getting "imported content is empty" error?

Thanks you guys!!

Comment: Yikes but thanks good to know!! Sorry that I got you banned!

Answer (score 0):

there is a protective layer on that site called "Project Security" which renders out all **scraping** attempts (at least for me)

[image]